# what version of Google Mobile Ads SDK is Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds using?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm on Firebase but am currently using Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds in a Xamarin.Forms project. Everything is working well.

i received an email from firebase that said Starting January 23, 2018, we will no longer be supporting Android and iOS Google Mobile Ads SDKs lower than version 7.0.0. To continue serving ads from AdMob after this date, please upgrade to the latest Google Mobile Ads SDK.

Is Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds compliant (7.0.0 or >) i'm not sure how to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, Xamarin has never released a Google Mobile Ads SDK version that is using a Google version older than 7.0 (released 2015‑02‑03 from Google).

Xamarin's nuget package versions **match** the version from Google. The latest `Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds` package is `7.24.1`, thus it is using Google's Mobile Ads `7.24.1` (2017‑9‑27).

You can also at runtime use const string `GoogleMobileAdsVersionString` to retrieve the version you are using.

FYI: That is currently three dot releases behind the official releases from Google:

> `7.27.0`   2017‑12‑13
>
> - Added support for native video mediation. Native mediation adapters must implement the mediaView method on GADMediatedNativeAppInstallAd and GADMediatedNativeContentAd and return their media view.
>
> `7.26.0`   2017‑11‑17
>
> - iPhone X support.
>     For full screen ads, the default close button now renders within the safe area.
>     Removed the nativeAd property from GADAdChoicesView and GADMediaView.
>     Limits SDK interactions with Apple's StoreServices to once per session, at app launch.
>
> `7.25.0`   2017‑10‑25
>
> - Native Mediation: Adapters now get the call to mediatedNativeAd:didRenderInView:viewController: as soon as a native ad is associated with a native ad view, instead of waiting for that native ad view to be visible.
>     Native Mediation: Adapters now get a call to mediatedNativeAdDidUntrackView: with a nil view when the tracked view gets deallocated.
>
> `7.24.1`   2017‑9‑27
>
> - Updates the way the SDK interacts with Apple's StoreServices.

It all open source from Xamarin, so personally I grab Xamarin's source (and update the bindings where needed) and the latest release from Google. (i.e. I needed iPhone X support and Xamarin has not release a package that includes `7.26.0` yet)

- https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/download
- https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/tree/master/Google.MobileAds

Comment: Thanks for the detail.  I was hoping someone would give me some education on how to tell the next time I need to figure out something like this.  And you did!